# php sdk google analytics api , multiple accounts doenst give me the right data

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

im using the Google Api PHP v0.5.0(http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) , to access to Google Analytics, im able to connect using the token (oauth) without any problem, but when i try to switch to other account , its retrieves me the data from the first account i logged in, each account has their own client id, client secret, developer key, and token, so when i switch to other account i just create a instance using the information of that specific account

i realized that are some cookies from google but i delete them and still retrieves me data from the first account i logged, i dont see any function to destroy session or logout or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out the problem, actually wasnt any problem, the token you get from google is from the account you are logged in, because i "allow" the application with the same account, i was generate the token from the same user each time, i didnt understand that well until now